# Create an Array from two Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-feed-api

I'm working with Google Feed API for RSS feeds and need to add the values of the fetched RSS feed item array to create another array (that is used to create a javascript bar graph of the data).

The array would be this:

```
arrayOfData = new Array(
     [THE_FEED_ITEM_CONTENT, THE_FEED_ITEM_TITLE,'#cccccc']
);
```

I'm using [jqBarGraph](http://workshop.rs/jqbargraph/) for the graph.

For context, this is the part of the code that displays the feed and subsequently grabs that values that I need to create the array mentioned. It is currently a part of creating a table of the of the data coming through the feed:

```
function displayfeed(result){

if (!result.error){
var thefeeds=result.feed.entries
for (var i=0; i<thefeeds.length; i++) {
xlabel+="<td>" +  thefeeds[i].title + "</td>";
xdata+="<td>" + thefeeds[i].content + "</td>";
}
rssoutput+=xlabel + "</tr></thead>" + xdata + "</tr></tbody></table>"
feedcontainer.innerHTML=rssoutput
}
else
alert("Error fetching feeds!")
}

window.onload=function(){
rssfeedsetup()
}
```

Here is an example of the array used to create the javascript graphs (with absolute values):

```
arrayOfData = new Array(
     [10.3,'Jan','#cccccc'],
     [15.2,'Feb','#cccccc'],
     [13.1,'Mar','#cccccc'],
);
```

Now, I need that array to be filled with:

```
arrayOfData = new Array(
     [thefeeds[i].content, thefeeds[i].title,'#cccccc']
);
```

The idea, of course, is to fill the array above with each item on the RSS feed. One line filled out with thefeeds[i].content & [thefeeds[i].title and so and so forth.

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: It's really not clear what you want here, can you reduce or clarify the problem? Also, the linked answer is PHP, whereas this is a JavaScript question.

Comment: D'oh. Sorry about that, I removed it. It did show the concept, but certainly no code relevance!

I did clarify it some, hopefully it helps.

I'm essentially combining two attributes of one array into a new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var thefeeds=result.feed.entries;
var arrayOfData = new Array();
for (var i=0; i<thefeeds.length; i++) {
  arrayOfData.push([thefeeds[i].content,thefeeds[i].title,'#cccccc']) 
}
```

Comment: A foreach loop (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) is a bit more elegant in this situation.

Comment: @dtech except `for..in` will also iterate over properties that aren't indices but are enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array. This is not combining as it is usually defined (done with `Array.concat` in javascript)

```
var arrayOfData = new Array();
for(var feed in thefeeds) {
    arrayOfData.push(feed.content, feed.title, '#cccccc');
}
```